# Graph theory results about the spread of a boolean value over a graph (e.g. epidemic contamination)?

Tags: graph-theory, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, random-graphs

Let's say we have an **undirected graph of 50 millions of nodes** (let's say a first approximation of a country with closed borders).

Let's say there is a link/edge between node $a$ and node $b$ if person $a$ and $b$ have met with distance < 1 meter today.

On each node, you have a boolean value `True`/`False` (or "contaminated+recovered+dead" / "not contaminated").

**Which part of graph theory and which theorems give us asymptotic information for a question like:**

We put value `True` for 1000 random nodes on the graph, and `False` everywhere else. Let's say that after 1 iteration, there is a probability $p=0.5$ that if $a$ has a link with $b$ who has `True`, then $a$ becomes `True` too (contamination).
**Question: after $n$ days, how many people have `True`?**

Of course this will depend on the topology of the graph. Are there ways to answer to this question, given a few constants that describe the graph's topology, like:

$$\alpha = \text{average number of edges for nodes}$$

?

What are the relevant keywords in graph theory to search about this? (sadly, graph theory wasn't taught where I studied maths at university).

---

Numerical simulation: I more or less know how to simulate such a process with code (e.g. Python), and how to observe such things, but I was interested in the part of graph theory that can give answers.

Comment: Arguably this is rather stochastics than graph theory, since the question is more about quantities of probability (estimated number of people infected) than the structural properties of graphs. I would look up markov chains and probability matrices...

Comment: @PrudiiArca Yes, but I really want to take the topology of the graph into consideration. More precisely: if you have a single long line like this: `x_1 -- x_2 -- ... -- x_N` , it's totally different than a 2D graph with loops etc.

Comment: This is a quite difficult problem. The state 'number of infected individuals' is not a Markov process (the number of infected individuals in the next iteration depends not only on the number of infected now, but also on their configuration and the underlying topology). In other words, the transition rate cannot be expressed solely in terms of the number of infected nodes (unless the underlying topology is trivial, i.e., complete or totally disconnected). It depends in an intricate manner on the underlying topology. You may consider checking the literature of interacting particle systems.

Comment: I have very limited knowledge of stochastics, so maybe my hint towards markov chains was wrong. I know of graph theory though and was thinking of the topology of the graph as represented by the adjacency matrix. My guess was that modifying it by replacing 1s by appropriate probabilities may solve the problem. But I notice now that it is quite a bit more complicated than that...

Comment: @PrudiiArca: Markov chains or processes are certainly appropriate (and definitely not wrong). The vector conveying the states of all individual (infected or not infected) is Markov. The process 'number of infected individuals over time' is not Markov and its qualitative analysis becomes difficult because the transition rates are sensitive to the topology. For instance, if 30 individuals are infected now and they are intermingled with other healthy individuals, the number of infected individuals will increase faster than if they were clumped together.